# Google benchmark fixture: reuse vectors across multiple benchmarks

Tags: c++, microbenchmark, google-benchmark

I want to run multiple benchmarks using google benchmark library after loading up a large file. I use the following code for this purpose. The function `read_collection()` loads the contents of the file and the benchmark `Build` processes the contents from `coll`.

```
#define COLLECTION 'w'

class BuildFixture : public ::benchmark::Fixture {
 public:
     std::unique_ptr<Collection> coll;

     BuildFixture() {
        cout << "Constructor\n";
        coll = std::make_unique<Collection>(Collection(COLLECTION));
        coll->read_collection();
     }

     ~BuildFixture() {
         cout << "Destroy collection\n";
         coll.reset();
     }
};

BENCHMARK_DEFINE_F(BuildFixture, Build1)(benchmark::State& state) {
    nrows = static_cast<size_t>(state.range(0));
    for (auto _ : state) {
       // Do something with coll and nrows
    }
}

BENCHMARK_DEFINE_F(BuildFixture, Build2)(benchmark::State& state) {
    nrows = static_cast<size_t>(state.range(0));
    for (auto _ : state) {
       // Something else with coll and nrows
    }
}



BENCHMARK_REGISTER_F(BuildFixture, Build1)->Arg(10);
BENCHMARK_REGISTER_F(BuildFixture, Build2)->Arg(20);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

When I run this code, each benchmark with arguments 10 and 20 executes the constructor (for a total of two times), runs the benchmarks and then calls the destructors. So the output looks like

```
Constructor
Constructor
.. (benchmarking outputs)..
Destroy collection                                                                              
Destroy collection
```

This ends up taking too much time to read the (same) file multiple times and also takes up additional memory for holding the same data for several benchmarks. I am also worried whether the results will get affected by page faults. Therefore, I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to avoid having to read the file twice as it would save some execution time (although this time is not counted in the benchmark).
2. (If not) How can I restructure multiple benchmark code in a way that each benchmark calls the constructor, performs benchmarking, destructs and then move on to the next benchmark? (without having to use multiple `main` functions, of course)

**Update 1**

The benchmarks I need to register are different. I am not looking to pass different args to the same benchmark. I have updated the question accordingly with `Build1` and `Build2`.

Comment: In traditional test frameworks you'd want some kind of shared fixture. There seems to be support for this. See this github issue: https://github.com/google/benchmark/issues/109

Comment: @Voo Interesting. My understanding is not really great here. Wouldn't a new `State` object be created for each iteration? In that case, each iteration will end up reading the file in full. I was hoping for more of a read the file once and use it among multiple benchmarks scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you define your own `main`, you can create a global collection and reference it from every benchmark.

However, you can also avoid the issue by only registering the benchmark once:

```cpp
BENCHMARK_REGISTER_F(BuildFixture, Build)->Arg(10)->Arg(20)
```

Comment: Global collection would work. Unfortunately, I have different benchmarks so I can't use `BENCHMARK_REGISTER_F(BuildFixture, Build)->Arg(10)->Arg(20)` format. I should have clarified that in the question

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour if you use `SetUp` and `TearDown` instead of the ctor and dtor?